# How do I increase the font for Visual Studio 2022 Search Screen

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When I hit CTRL + F, the following window for search pops up, but the font is relatively very small to the main window.  How do I fix this?

[image: Visual Studio 2022 Search Screen]

Comment: You can increase the text font in the code window using ctrl+ combination. You can use a larger font, finally, you can use Windows Magnifier built-in Application.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2019 it's

> Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors

then from the "Show settings for:" drop down you can select

> Environment

Where you can alter the default font for all VS Window and menu text.
NB: This may be more than you are willing to change

Coding/editor windows will remain the same.
Fonts for all editors is in

> Text Editor